# Starting activity from Fragment doesn't work Xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to start an activity from fragment with Xamarin.Android. This is the fragment

```
public class ChoirFragment : TourFragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(page, container, false);
        Button button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(StartActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

When I click on button, the click does nothing :(.

And I don't know why debugger doesn't stop at OnCreateView.

If you need more information do not hesitate to ask me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the name of the class for the activity you want to start? If it is not StartActivity, then that is your issue.

Comment: Yes, the name is StartActivity, i checked that before. Yesterday, my code was "cached" by vs (maybe Xamarin problems). I will test again this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`, I don't know why this would work for you to load your fragment view, by my side I should return the `view` for layout.

Anyway, the following demo works for me:

```cs
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Choir_Fragment, container, false);
    Button button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
    button.Click += delegate
    {
        //var intent = new Intent(this.Context, typeof(StartActivity));
        var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(StartActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    };
    return view;
}
```

Here is more info about my project:
[image]

If this demo is needed, please leave a comment.

Comment: this is correct, but my problem was vs2015 was running old code. Maybe Windows Emulator has a problem with this

Comment: @user3535054, ok, sometimes when I met such problem, I create a new project and test those code again, anyway, thx for marking my answer.

Comment: That is really annoying for me, Xamarin have problems to debug and your partial solution is viable at this moment. Thanks!

Comment: This is working fine but what does this.Context mean here @Grace Feng - MSFT ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);` to `return view`